# How to get json value from response ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

My json response is like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXSXi.jpg

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c4ded7d2934f62fb68a276cfb118d52e

I want display HotelNo, RmGrade, Meal and TotalRate

I try like this :

```
...
    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $.each(response, function() {
                          $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                                // console.log(k);
                                // console.log(v);

                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $parent.find('.loading').html(v.HotelNo + '<br>' + v.RmGrade + '<br>' + v.Meal + '<br>' + v.TotalRate);
                                }, 2000);

                         });
                        });
                    }
...
```

But it's not working

How to get json value from response ajax correctly?

Any solution to solve my problem

Thank you very much

Comment: give a sample of your json please, image is not enough

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers, look here : http://pastebin.com/6zpi5wA2

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers, or see here : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c4ded7d2934f62fb68a276cfb118d52e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to help you if you give us a sample of your JSON, but in the meantime, I suggest to loop on `response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel` instead of `response`:

```
  success: function (response) {

     $.each(response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel, function() {
           setTimeout(function () {
                   $parent.find('.loading').html(v.HotelNo + '<br>' + v.RmGrade + '<br>' + v.Meal + '<br>' + v.TotalRate);
                    }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Waiting for your JSON.

As I mentionned before, you will not have access to things like `HotelNo` by looping only through `response`. Here is a working solution:
`

```
 for(i=0; i<response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel.length; i++){

           console.log(js.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo);

    }
```

`response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel` is an array of objects.

Comment: I was talking about a sample not a copy paste of a long one, just a sample with some few values to test with

Comment: or look here : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c4ded7d2934f62fb68a276cfb118d52e

Comment: Any solution to solve my problem? I am still difficulties

Comment: I found one give me please some few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101611/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-whiteletters-in-blankpapers).

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is that you are getting an array.
You dont have to have loop inside loop.

```
success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $.each(response, function(index, v) {


                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $parent.find('.loading').html(v.HotelNo + '<br>' + v.RmGrade + '<br>' + v.Meal + '<br>' + v.TotalRate);
                                }, 2000);


                        });
                    }
```

Comment: It's not working. It looks like it needs loop inside loop. Try to see the json response again